# SQLで無いデータを表示させたい

Tags: mysql, sql

一日の売上を一月分表示したいです。

売上テーブルには、
日付と時間、その売上額が保存されているものとします。

```
売上 日付
--------------------------
1000   2015-01-04 15:00:22
1300   2015-01-05 15:00:22
1200   2015-01-10 10:14:52
 400   2015-01-11 09:02:01
1200   2015-01-11 11:04:22
5000   2015-01-20 15:50:22
1200   2015-01-20 19:42:19
5000   2015-01-21 14:00:22
```

以下のSQLを実行するとその日付ごとの売り上げの合計値が求められるはずですが、

```
SELECT 日付 , SUM(売上額) FROM 売上
WHERE 日付　BETWEEN　'2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
GROUP BY 日付
```

結果

```
売上 日付
--------------------------
1000   2015-01-04
1300   2015-01-05
1200   2015-01-10
1600   2015-01-11
6200   2015-01-20
5000   2015-01-21
```

と表示されるはずですが、

もし売り上げが無い日（例えばここに2015-01-01の日付で売上を0として）表示するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか

Comment: そのSQLだと「日付と時間」ごとに売り上げが合計されるので、期待されているようにはならないですよね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

表示したい日付をすべて用意して、それに対して売上を LEFT JOIN すると、表示したい日付がすべて出現します
売上のなかった日の売上の値は NULL になってしまいますので、NULL を 0 に変換してあげます

postgresql なら、generate_series関数で日付の連続をその場で生成することができ、便利です
mysqlでも同様のことができると思います

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/1970

```
WITH 売上 AS (
SELECT * FROM (
VALUES
    (1000,'2015-01-04 15:00:22'::timestamp),
    (1300,'2015-01-05 15:00:22'::timestamp),
    (1200,'2015-01-10 10:14:52'::timestamp),
    (400,'2015-01-11 09:02:01'::timestamp),
    (1200,'2015-01-11 11:04:22'::timestamp),
    (5000,'2015-01-20 15:50:22'::timestamp),
    (1200,'2015-01-20 19:42:19'::timestamp),
    (5000,'2015-01-21 14:00:22'::timestamp)
) AS T(売上額, 日付)
)
SELECT
    COALESCE(売上.売上額, 0) AS 売上額,
    COALESCE(売上.日付, dateSeq) AS 日付
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        generate_series(
            '2015-01-01'::DATE,
            '2015-12-31',
            '1 day'
        )
) AS T(dateSeq)
LEFT JOIN
    売上 ON (売上.日付::date = dateSeq::date)
ORDER BY
    dateSeq, 日付
;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQLを今すぐ使える環境が無いので試せないのですが……

集計したい期間について毎日の売り上げをゼロとしたテンポラリのテーブルを作成し、
それをUNIONでくっつけて集計すれば同等のことはできると思います。

テンポラリテーブルを動的に作成するか、事前に用意しておくかは作り方次第かと。

Answer (score 0):

私なら集計したい期間の実テーブルを作成し、対象となるテーブルを Left outer join で結合します。

Answer (score 0):

MySQLユーザーのために追記しておきます。

```
CREATE TABLE source (cat int, price int, date timestamp);
INSERT INTO source (cat, price, date)
VALUES
    (1, 1000,'2022-01-04 15:00:22'),
    (2, 1300,'2022-02-05 15:00:22'),
    (2, 1200,'2022-03-10 10:14:52'),
    (1, 400,'2022-04-11 09:02:01'),
    (1, 1200,'2022-05-11 11:04:22'),
    (2, 5000,'2022-06-20 15:50:22'),
    (1, 1200,'2022-07-20 19:42:19'),
    (2, 5000,'2022-08-21 14:00:22');

SELECT
    all_months.p_month,
    IFNULL(SUM(source.price), 0) AS t_price
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            date_format(date, '%Y-%m') AS p_month
        FROM
            source
    ) all_months
    
LEFT JOIN source ON all_months.p_month = date_format(source.date, '%Y-%m') AND source.cat = 1

GROUP BY
    all_months.p_month;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7485ac/1